# Breeze entityquery with expanded child entity is not correctly assigned to knockout observable array

Tags: entity-framework, knockout.js, asp.net-web-api, breeze

My JSON result that I get back from my Breeze WebApi does not get correctly assigned to the knockout observable when a entity in the root of the graph previously exists as a child entity.

I have a entity User that has 1 or many Tenants, and a Tenant can have one or more Users (many to many relationship)

When running a query I get back the following JSON result (I only show the relevant parts):

```
{   "$id": "1",
    "$type": "Imp.Tenant, Imp",
    "TenantId": "14ff1ad0-6807-e411-befb-2c41384f9e84",
    "Users": [{
            "$id": "2",
            "$type": "Imp.User, Imp",
            "UserId": "d38a68c2-4407-e411-befb-2c41384f9e84",
            "Firstname": "Richard",
            "Tenants": [{
                    "$ref": "1"
                },{
                    "$id": "3",
                    "$type": "Imp.Tenant, Imp",
                    "TenantId": "5c8d8852-6907-e411-befb-2c41384f9e84",
                   "Users": [{
                            "$ref": "2"
                        }
                    ],
               }
            ],
           "CurrentTenant": {
                "$ref": "1"
            },
            "CurrentTenantId": "14ff1ad0-6807-e411-befb-2c41384f9e84",
       }
    ],
   "CreatedBy": {
        "$ref": "2"
    },
    "CreatedById": "d38a68c2-4407-e411-befb-2c41384f9e84"
},{
    "$ref": "3"
}
```

I run the following query (Typescript code):

```
var query = breeze.EntityQuery
            .from("userTenants")
            .withParameters({ userId: userId });

return query
            .using(this.BreezeEntityManager)
            .execute()
            .then((data) => this.Tenants(<Imp.Tenant[]>data.results))
```

And the breeze controller looks like this:

```
    public IQueryable<Tenant> userTenants(Guid userId)
    {                   
        var User = _ContextProvider.Context.Users
            .Include("Tenants")
            .FirstOrDefault(x => x.UserId == userId);
        return User.Tenants.AsQueryable();
    }
```

It seems that because entity $ref 1 (ID "14ff1ad0-6807-e411-befb-2c41384f9e84") is also a child entity from Users it gets referred to as $ref 3 at the end of the JSON string.

When trying to assign this value to the knockoutObservableArray, only the first Tenant entity is correctly assigned, but the second ($ref 3) gets a function as display in the watch window:

```
function(){
    return mc.refMap[nodeRefId];
}
```

How can I retrieve all the Tenants that a User is linked to?

Comment: Sorry, I can't repro your issue. Can you create a simple repro solution and send it to breeze@ideablade.com?

Comment: Is Tenants to Users a Many to Many relationship?

Comment: @PW Kad Yes, Tenant to User is many to many.

Comment: Breeze and breeze queries don't support many to many relationships

Comment: Yes, that is true, but is that the problem here? I filter out in de controller as far as I can see. The data that is going over the wire does have the many to many relationship, but all the information is there.

Comment: @JayTraband : I've created a repro solution. You can find it here: https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=F67796BA2A931950!285793&authkey=!APDeewGIlAFbYKI&ithint=file%2c.zip

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth, I think I just worked around the same problem.  The root cause seemed to be that one of my many-to-one navigation properties, using EF's default conventions, wasn't surfacing a referential constraint. The navigation property was being silently ignored on the client side.

In my case, the first occurrence of an object that the JSON encoding references later (i.e., via $ref) was in this ignored property, so wasn't getting added to the mapping context.  While I might not have cared about that object in the context of the navigation property, I did care about it as a root level object that appeared in the result of the original query.

The workaround was to map the underlying foreign key constraint.